# numerically integrating $\int_0^{10} \cos x^3 dx $

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

The integrand is highly oscillating at the right end of the interval.

I thought of this way

$$ I = \int_0^1 \cos x^3 d x + \int_1^{10} \cos x^3 d x = \int_0^1 \cos x^3 d x + \int_1^{1000} \cos y d y^{1/3} . $$

The second integral is free of singularity now. But the problem is that the interval is too big. Moreover, there is much cancellation there.

Do anyone have any better idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'll consider only the last integral of the form
$$
I = \int_1^{1000} f(y) \cos y dy.
$$
Let's split the integration domains into $2\pi$ segments like
$$
I = \int_1^\pi f(y) \cos y dy + \int_{\pi}^{3\pi} f(y) \cos y dy + \dots
+ \int_{315\pi}^{317\pi} f(y) \cos y dy + \int_{317\pi}^{1000} f(y) \cos y dy.
$$
Again, considering only the middle terms we can write
$$
I' = \sum_{k=1}^{158} \int_{(2k-1)\pi}^{(2k+1)\pi} f(y) \cos y dy.
$$
Each integral can now be converted by a variable transformation to an integral for $[-\pi, \pi]$ domain:
$$
I' = \sum_{k=1}^{158} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(y + 2k\pi) \cos z dz.
$$
Moreover, the sum and the integral sign can now be interchanged:
$$
I' = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{158} f(z + 2k\pi)}_{g(z)} \cos z dz.
$$
Not the original problem is reduced to evaluating only five integrals without highly-oscillating features. Instead you need to evaluate $g(z)$ which may be quite expensive.

Comment: This is a quite smart idea. It is very promising. I will have a try.

Comment: But I am not sure whether the idea of deforming the contour and using the method of steepest descent will work too.